# Windows 8 RT XAML MediaElement controls overlaid on top of video

Tags: video, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have seen numerous examples of the MediaElement used for video playback in Windows RT XAML applications.

I would like to have the controls overlay the video, rather than place controls within the AppBar or elsewhere in my view i.e. play / pause, full-screen etc.

[image]

I haven't seen any examples of this, just basic buttons placed within the XAML. Can anyone provide a good place to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Player framework](http://playerframework.codeplex.com/) is one of good framework for media playback. Then also if you want to create your own player interface then do it like given below. You can use `Opacity` property for transparency.

```
<Grid Width="339" Height="278">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height=".5*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <MediaElement Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Source="Assets/Sample.mp4" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Opacity=".4" Background="Black" />
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource PlayAppBarButtonStyle}" />
        <Slider Width="150" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <Button Style="{StaticResource PlayAppBarButtonStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Looks good. I think I've noticed this in use in a number of applications too.